# Conditional rendering page loads wrong page

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on loading this Black Friday page.  If it is expired it should return the expired page. If not, it should return the Black Friday page.

Issue: when the promo is expired and the user loads the page. It will load the Black Friday page for 1/3 sec, then load the expired page.  I end up with a wonky looking expired page.

How can I fix this issue?

```
function BlackFridayPages({ page, expiredPage, globalSettings }) {
  const blackFridayEndDate = new Date('2023-02-20') //Change this to test
  const now = new Date();

  const expired = blackFridayEndDate < now

  if (expired) {
    return (
      <ExpiredPage expiredPage={expiredPage} />
    );
   }

  return (
    <>
     <BlackFridayPage /> 
    </>

  ); //no extra conditional because I want it pre-rendered. Am I not allowed to do this?
}


export default BlackFridayPages;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this issue is to use the state to hold the status of the promotion. Here is a code sandbox!

[image: Edit hopeful-fog-119gf7]